# Select the minimum over blocks of observations

Tags: stata

I am trying to make Stata select the minimum value of `ice_cream` eaten by every person (`Amanda`, `Christian`, `Paola`) so that I end up with just 3 rows:

```
person  ice_cream
    Amanda  16
    Amanda  27
    Amanda  29
    Amanda  40
    Amanda  96
    Amanda  97
    Christian   19
    Christian   23
    Christian   26
    Christian   27
    Christian   28
    Christian   34
    Christian   62
    Christian   70
    Christian   78
    Paola   5
    Paola   11
    Paola   28
    Paola   97
```

Comment: It's helpfully clear what you want, but strictly, you want the minimum over blocks of observations, as for Stata an observation is a single row or record in the dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer that avoids creating a new variable:

```
sort person ice_cream
by person: keep if _n == 1
```

Comment: `by person: keep if _n == 1` basically means "keep the first observation of each person"?

Comment: Yes, but @lmo sorted first, so that selects the minimum as you wish.

Comment: @pdesp the `_n ` method is super useful and can be applied in many a data cleaning / manipulation scenario.

Comment: `bysort person (ice_cream) : keep if _n == 1` gets you there in one line.

Comment: @ Nick Cox I really have to start using that parenthetical piece in my code.

Comment: Here is a tutorial I came across: http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0004

Answer (score 4):

A one-line solution

```
collapse (min) ice_cream, by(person)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
* Generate a variable with the group minimums    
sort person
by person: egen Min = min(ice_cream)
* Only keep observations with same value as group minimums
keep if Min == ice_cream
* Delete minimum variable
drop Min
```

**Note:** This will leave only observations with a minimum value for ice_cream. If multiple observations in a group have the minimum value for ice_cream then you will have multiple observations for that group (Note this is not in the above data but may be likely if for instance ice_cream was a factor variable). If you wanted a unique observation per group you could then add:

```
duplicates drop person, force
```

Comment: This fails to satisfy the requirement if there are ties for minimum. In that case, you would select more observations than needed.

Comment: Ties for lowest value are very common with counts and even with measured variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply display the minimum value of `ice_cream` eaten
by `Amanda`, `Christian` and `Paola`, but *without* altering your dataset, you can
use the `summarize` command instead:

```
clear

input str20 person ice_cream
Amanda  16
Amanda  27
Amanda  29
Amanda  40
Amanda  96
Amanda  97
Christian   19
Christian   23
Christian   26
Christian   27
Christian   28
Christian   34
Christian   62
Christian   70
Christian   78
Paola   5
Paola   11
Paola   28
Paola   97
end

bysort person: summarize ice_cream

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-> person = Amanda

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
   ice_cream |          6    50.83333    36.18517         16         97

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-> person = Christian

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
   ice_cream |          9    40.77778    22.63171         19         78

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-> person = Paola

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
   ice_cream |          4       35.25    42.30347          5         97
```