# Select lowest value per group

Tags: grouping, panel, stata, min

This question is related to [Stata: select the minimum of each observation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555139/stata-select-the-minimum-of-each-observation).

I have data as follows:

```
clear
input str4 id int eventdate byte dia_bp_copy int sys_bp_copy
"pat"  15698 100 140
"pat"  16183  80 120
"pat"  19226  98 155
"pat"  19375  80 130
"sue"  14296  80 120
"sue"  14334  88 127
"sue"  14334  96 158
"sue"  14334  84 136
"sue"  14403  86 124
"sue"  14403  88 134
"sue"  14403  90 156
"sue"  14403  86 134
"sue"  14403  90 124
"sue"  14431  80 120
"sue"  14431  80 140
"sue"  14431  80 130
"sue"  15456  80 130
"sue"  15501  80 120
"sue"  15596  80 120
"mary" 14998  90 154
"mary" 15165  91 179
"mary" 15280  91 156
"mary" 15386  81 154
"mary" 15952  77 133
"mary" 15952  80 144
"mary" 16390  91 159
end
```

Some people have multiple readings on one day, eg see Sue on 31st March 1999. I want to select the lowest reading per day.

Here is my code which gets me some of the way. It is clunky and clumsy and I am looking for help to do what I want to do in a more straightforward way.

```
*make flag for repeat observations on same day

sort id eventdate  
by id: gen flag =1 if eventdate==eventdate[_n-1]
by id: gen flag2=1 if eventdate==eventdate[_n+1]
by id: gen flag3 =1 if flag==1 | flag2==1
drop flag flag2

* group repeat observations together

egen group = group(id flag3 eventdate)

* find lowest `sys_bp_copy` value per group

bys group (eventdate flag3): egen low_sys=min(sys_bp_copy)

*remove the observations where the lowest value of `sys_bp`_copy doesn't exist

bys group: gen remove =1 if low_sys!=sys_bp_copy
drop if remove==1 & group !=.
```

****Problems with this and where I'd like help** **

The problem with the above approach is that for Sue, two of her repeat readings have the same val of `sys_bp_copy`. So my approach above leaves me with multiple readings for her.

In this instance I would like to refer to the `dia_sys_copy` and select the lowest value there to help me pick out one row per person when multiple readings are in place. Code for this is below - but there must be a simpler way to do this?

```
drop flag3 remove group

sort id eventdate
by id: gen flag =1 if eventdate==eventdate[_n-1]
by id: gen flag2=1 if eventdate==eventdate[_n+1]
by id: gen flag3 =1 if flag==1 | flag2==1

egen group = group(id flag3 eventdate)
bys group (eventdate flag3): egen low_dia=min(dia_bp_copy)

bys group: gen remove =1 if low_dia!=dia_bp_copy
drop if remove==1 & group !=.
```

Comment: ok, I'll edit to make more succint. hang on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lowest systolic pressure for a patient on a particular day is easy to define: you just sort and look for the lowest value in each block of observations.

We can refine the definition by breaking ties on systolic by values of diastolic. That's another sort. In this example, that makes no difference.

```
clear
input str4 id int eventdate byte dia_bp_copy int sys_bp_copy
"pat"  15698 100 140
"pat"  16183  80 120
"pat"  19226  98 155
"pat"  19375  80 130
"sue"  14296  80 120
"sue"  14334  88 127
"sue"  14334  96 158
"sue"  14334  84 136
"sue"  14403  86 124
"sue"  14403  88 134
"sue"  14403  90 156
"sue"  14403  86 134
"sue"  14403  90 124
"sue"  14431  80 120
"sue"  14431  80 140
"sue"  14431  80 130
"sue"  15456  80 130
"sue"  15501  80 120
"sue"  15596  80 120
"mary" 14998  90 154
"mary" 15165  91 179
"mary" 15280  91 156
"mary" 15386  81 154
"mary" 15952  77 133
"mary" 15952  80 144
"mary" 16390  91 159
end

bysort id eventdate (sys) : gen lowest = sys[1] 

bysort id eventdate (sys dia) : gen lowest_2 = sys[1] 

egen tag = tag(id eventdate) 

count if lowest != lowest_2 

list id event dia sys lowest* if tag, sepby(id) 

     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
     |   id   eventd~e   dia_bp~y   sys_bp~y   lowest   lowest_2 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | mary      14998         90        154      154        154 |
  2. | mary      15165         91        179      179        179 |
  3. | mary      15280         91        156      156        156 |
  4. | mary      15386         81        154      154        154 |
  5. | mary      15952         77        133      133        133 |
  7. | mary      16390         91        159      159        159 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------|
  8. |  pat      15698        100        140      140        140 |
  9. |  pat      16183         80        120      120        120 |
 10. |  pat      19226         98        155      155        155 |
 11. |  pat      19375         80        130      130        130 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------|
 12. |  sue      14296         80        120      120        120 |
 13. |  sue      14334         88        127      127        127 |
 16. |  sue      14403         86        124      124        124 |
 21. |  sue      14431         80        120      120        120 |
 24. |  sue      15456         80        130      130        130 |
 25. |  sue      15501         80        120      120        120 |
 26. |  sue      15596         80        120      120        120 |
     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

`egen` is very useful (disclosure of various interests there), but the main idea here is just that `by:` defines groups of observations and you can do that for two or more variables, and not just one -- and control the sort order too. As it were, about half of `egen` is built on such ideas, but it can be easiest and best to use them directly.

Comment: I totally made a mountain out of a molehill there. Thanks for this and patiently explaining the egen command.

Comment: Don't worry: sometimes it takes 20 years to be able to see a solution in 20  minutes rather than 20 hours... See e.g. http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0004

Comment: thanks very much for link to article. #romewasn'tbuiltinaday :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand:

Create an identifier for same id and same date

```
egen temp_group = group(id eventdate)
```

Find the first occurrence based on lowest `sys_bp_copy` and then lowest `dia_bp_copy`

```
bys temp_group (sys_bp_copy dia_bp_copy): gen temp_first = _n
keep if temp_first == 1
drop temp*
```

or in 1 line as suggest in comment:

```
bys id eventdate (sys_bp_copy dia_bp_copy): keep if _n==1
```

Comment: Same basic idea as mine (upvote!), but the variable created by `group()` is superfluous. If you rewrite your second command as `bysort id eventdate (sys dia)` then we have the same solution. Again, the `temp_first` variable is superfluous: you can `keep` the first observation within the framework of `by:`.